# ValueError: cannot convert float NaN to integer after already using dropna()

Tags: python, pandas, csv

```
import pandas as pd   
import csv 
import numpy as np

readfile = pd.read_csv('51.csv')
filevalues= readfile.loc[readfile['Customer'].str.contains('Lam Dep', na=False), 'Jul-18\nQty']
filevalues.replace(" ", "")
filevalues = filevalues.replace(r'^\s*$', np.nan, regex=True) 
filevalues.dropna()
int_series = filevalues.astype(int)
calculated_series = int_series.apply(lambda x: x*(1/1.2))

print(calculated_series)
```

In my csv files, there are cells with NaNs and empty strings ( or perhaps white spaces) I attempt to get rid of cells with white spaces and drop the NaN values, however I run into the error:

```
ValueError: cannot convert float NaN to integer
```

The other methods I have found on stackoverflow have proven to not work for this code. Any idea of how I can move forward? This is especially confusing because my code specifies to drop NaNs and then the error states: cannot convert float NaN to integer

Comment: You probably need `filevalues.dropna(inplace=True)` or `filevalues = filevalues.dropna()` since, `dropna()` does not remove in original dataframe when you don't specify `inplace=True` instead it returns `dataframe` with with NA entries dropped.

Comment: @student I just ran that and gave me the same error.

Comment: Can you try using `filevalues.dropna(how='any',inplace=True)`?

Comment: @student Tried it, and sadly gave the same error.

Comment: Can you look into the output for `filevalues[filevalues.isnull()]`?

Comment: @student Would you please be able to explain what that function does and/or tell me how I am supposed to integrate that in code- and what I will be looking for with this

Comment: It will return rows with `null` values, so after dropna, may be you can chech, you can look into documentation https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.isnull.html

Comment: @student, well the same error runs, however if I remove the last two lines in the main part of the code, and print(filevalues), the pandas dataframe prints out.

Comment: Ok, try `filevalues = filevalues.replace(" ", "", regex=True)` instead of `filevalues.replace(" ", "")`

Comment: @student yup, still running the same error, perhaps there is something else that is fundamentally wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try as following:

```
filevalues = filevalues.replace(" ", "", regex=True)
filevalues.replace("", np.nan, inplace=True) # replace empty string with np.nan
filevalues.dropna(inplace=True) # drop nan values
int_series = filevalues.astype(int) # change type

calculated_series = int_series.apply(lambda x: x*(1/1.2))

print(calculated_series)
```

Comment: `Happy Coding.`